# Debugging Azure application in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, azure

I've hosted an ASP.NET MVC4 application on Windows Azure.
Now I'm trying to debug the said application locally in Visual Studio.
Essentially I want to be able to insert breakpoints that gets hit by the live site.

I've looked at several references such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683670.aspx.

However I was not able to successfully apply it apparently.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Deploy the application in debug mode to the server.
- Connected to azure through visual studio. (By clicking "connect to Windows Azure" in server explorer).
- I've hit "Debug" but apparently the breakpoints I navigate to in live mode does not get hit.

What am I doing wrong? I need some pointers please!

when running through the publish wizard, this is all I see:

[image]

Comment: you appear to not have even understand the article. As there is no `hit "Debug"` for the `Debugging a cloud service in Windows Azure`. Instead there is `Attach Debugger`. I also would question the meaning of this remote debugging at all. You say ASP.NET MVC4 app. What is that thing you want to debug in Azure that you can't locally?

Comment: @astaykov
I'm having various issues with azure - for instance I can't log into accounts when on Azure which I CAN log into on localhost.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670444/can-log-in-locally-but-not-when-hosted-on-azure is a similar issue.

Therefore I want to debug in azure and not locally.

I may be rather lost so I'd appreciate if you could write me a few pointers as to how to do it.

Comment: With vs 2013 you can do like this: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/10/22/windows-azure-announcing-release-of-windows-azure-sdk-2-2-with-lots-of-goodies.aspx

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio
Ahh so it must be 2013 - I'm running VS2012 so I guess I'll have to upgrade

Comment: If you have a ultimate version, you can use Intellitrace too. My only question: Does Azure SDK 2.2 works with VS 2012? I don't know =(

Comment: Yes, it must be VS 2013 and the 2.2 SDK.  Debugging a deployed service is very new (as in within the week).

Comment: @Zebedee, if you use SQL Server Express locally I don't wonder that you can't login with provided credentials when deployed. You will have a better chance for solving your problem if you describe your specific problem, solutions that you have attempted and exact errors and stack traces. Simple asking for how to enable Remote Debugging will not help you and the question in its form is not suitable for StackOverflow!
for Mike and the others - remote debugging is possible with VS 2012 - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Remote-Debugging-Windows-dedaaec9 but it will not help Zebedee!

Answer (score 0):

VS2013 works seamlessly with Windows Azure cloud service remote dubugging without ado, yet VS2012 also has no problem with it, except that you have to enable Remote Debugging feature in the configuration via Management Portal.

Check it out. :)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/05/remote-debugging-a-window-azure-web-site-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx